# Extracting Groups From String

Tags: php, mysql

My end goal is to extract an oData $filter string and create a mySQL string in PHP.  For example:

```
(Field1 eq '(test)' or Field2 lt 20) and (beginsWith('test',Field3) or Field4 eq 3)
```

will become

```
(Field1 = '(test)' OR Field2 < 20) AND (Field3 LIKE 'test%' OR Field4 = 3)
```

It's not a matter of just doing a replace on the intrinsic keywords.  Inevitability I'd like to be able to figure out that beginsWith('test', Field3) is a field and I can then convert those parts into a mySQL statement.  What I've tried to do so far is create a WhereGroup class that stores Where classes so each one of the groups in parenthesis would have an instance then each statement would be in a Where instance.  Then I'd recursively generate the where statement.  But right now I'm just stuck trying to parse the strings intelligently.

Question is is there already something out there that can do something similar to this or am I on a path to create something from scratch?

Comment: Regular expressions?

Comment: can you show me an example of one constructed where it doesn't include the string test and 'test',Field3 as a WhereGroup?

Comment: `(\(('test',Field3)\))` is the regex to match `('test',Field3)`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: no, I want to get all of the parts but I don't want ('test',Field3) to be a match etc.  I'd get two parts "(Field1 eq '(test)' or Field2 lt 20)" and also "(beginsWith('test',Field3) or Field4 eq 3)"

Answer (score 2):

`.*(?=\s+a)` will get `(Field1 eq '(test)' or Field2 lt 20)`

`(\(b.*)` will get `(beginsWith('test',Field3) or Field4 eq 3)`

You can combine these, if you'd like, into an OR group -

```
.*(?=\s+a)|(\(b.*)
```

I am not sure that this is what you're after though. It seems that you're going to a great deal of trouble to turn something complex into something simple. Seems to me that you'll have to write several regex filters to extract strings.

Comment: that is on the right track but I need something generic, what exactly is (?=\s+a) doing?

Comment: The `?=` is a *positive lookahead*, looking for all things that go to a space followed by an 'a', without making the space and a part of the match.

Comment: I think I'm finding that using a few regular expressions like you eluded to at the end of your answer is the way to go.

Comment: I would think so because the strings that you're receiving would be a limited set, but there are a lot of strings within the set. You're going to have to meet several different conditions.